# Looper.loop not called but code in handler is still executed

Tags: java, android, looper

I am trying to understand how looper.loop works, and when to use it in my code. 
I have a bound service that has a runnable. Inside I have a handler that is used to hold code that updates the Ui. Here is the code.

```
private Runnable builder = new Runnable() {
public void run() 
{
  while(isThreadStarted == true)
  {
    if (newgps == 1)
     {  
         Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() { 
                         //some code that updates UI
                       }
                 }
           }
      }
  }
  looper.prepair
}
```

1. From what I read looper. prepare has to be called before the handler is made. But I noticed I didn’t do that but this code still works. How is this possible?
2. I want to fix this but im not sure where to put loper.loop. Because this handler is called many many times. Would it be ok if i put looper.loop right after .prepare? Then .quit when isThreadStarted == false?

Answer (score 0):

The `Handler` is associated with the UI thread, since you attach it to `Looper.getMainLooper()`. The UI thread prepares its `Looper`on application start, so that is nothing the application has to do itself.

Answer (score 0):

By using `Looper.getMainLooper()`, you get `Handler` of main thread and you are posting on main thread. Main thread has its looper prepared by system already when it is created.